# Deploy asp.net to iis

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

i try to publish my asp.net application to iis (v10.0), i get error in logs when running the application, maybe there is a problem with the database connection, but when I run my application on visual studio code 2022 there is no problem,

the logs info is, :

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mytubesite\
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware[3]
      Failed to determine the https port for redirect.
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
      Entity Framework Core 6.0.2 initialized 'ApplicationDBContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer:6.0.2' with options: None
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20004]
      An error occurred using the connection to database 'ASP.NETCoreIdentityCustom' on server 'DESKTOP-MA0E5C6'.
```

this my ApplicationDBContext :

```
using ASP.NETCoreIdentityCustom.Areas.Identity.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;
using ASP.NETCoreIdentityCustom.Models;
namespace ASP.NETCoreIdentityCustom.Areas.Identity.Data;

public class ApplicationDBContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDBContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDBContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Movie> Movie { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Comment> Comment { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new ApplicationUserEntityConfiguration());
    }
}


public class ApplicationUserEntityConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ApplicationUser>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ApplicationUser> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(u => u.FirstName).HasMaxLength(255);
        builder.Property(u => u.LastName).HasMaxLength(255);
    }
}
```

and the program.cs :

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using ASP.NETCoreIdentityCustom.Areas.Identity.Data;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ApplicationDBContextConnection");builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDBContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDBContext>();
// Add services to the container.


//builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

//app.UseDefaultFiles();
//app.UseStaticFiles();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

//app.MapControllers();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

and the appsetting.json:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "ApplicationDBContextConnection": "Data Source=DESKTOP-MA0E5C6;Initial Catalog=ASP.NETCoreIdentityCustom;Integrated Security=True",
    "MvcMovieContext": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=MvcMovieContext-cb93973d-d78f-4665-bef9-e5d55c116ab1;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }
}
```

Comment: That "_An error occurred using the connection to database_" sounds like your own message. You should also print the entire exception, as that contains important details

Comment: "Integrated Security=True" means the connection uses the identity the application is running under. From VS, that is _you_. From IIS, it's whatever is set there on the app-pool

Comment: Does the IIS app pool identity has permission to connect to DESKTOP-MA0E5C6 and can it login database? And what's the error message record in event viewer? Event viewer can record more detailed error message.